# Implementing EndlessRecyclerView on firestore database ui bindings

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

i am using firebase firestore and latest firebase ui bindings.
I want to add data into recyclerview when scrolling.

the project uses latest `'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.2.2'`

To recognize that we have reached end of RecyclerView i am  using this class  [EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener.java](https://gist.github.com/ssinss/e06f12ef66c51252563e)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported yet because we need to implement data slicing. However, I'd take a look at https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/pull/1178 and follow the issue: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/17.